# select all object keys that start with an underscore( _ )

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I need to make an array of all the keys (not values) in the following object where the key starts with an _ underscore...

In the following snippet i am trying to get `getSubscriptions()` to return `["_foo1", "_foo2"]`

```js
let myObj = {
  foo0: 'test',
  _foo1: 'test',
  _foo2: 'test',
  foo3: 'test',
};

function getSubscriptions(obj, cb) {
    // should return ["_foo1", "_foo2"]
    let ret = ["foo1", "_foo2"];
    return cb(ret);
}
getSubscriptions(myObj, (ret) => {
    if (match(ret, ["_foo1", "_foo2"]) ) { 
        $('.nope').hide();
        return $('.works').show(); 
    }
    $('.nope').show();
    $('.works').hide();
});

function match(arr1, arr2) {
    if(arr1.length !== arr2.length) { return false; } 
    for(var i = arr1.length; i--;) { 
        if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) { return false;}  
    }
    return true; 
}
```

```css
body {
    background: #333;
    color: #4ac388;
    padding: 2em;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 19px;
}
.nope {
  color: #ce4242;
}
.container div{
  padding: 1em;
  border: 3px dotted;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="works">It Works!</div>
    <div class="nope">
    Doesn't Work...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let myObj = {
  foo0: 'test',
  _foo1: 'test',
  _foo2: 'test',
  foo3: 'test',
};

let result = Object.keys(myObj).filter(v => v.startsWith("_"));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `Object.keys` with `filter`, and check if the first character is an underscore `_`:

```js
let myObj = {
  foo0: 'test',
  _foo1: 'test',
  _foo2: 'test',
  foo3: 'test',
};

const res = Object.keys(myObj).filter(([c]) => c == "_");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `getSubscriptions()` as follows

```
 function getSubscriptions(obj, cb) {
        let ret = Object.keys(myObj).filter(ele => ele.startsWith('_'))
        return cb(ret)
    }
```

- Object.keys(yourObject) : return keys of yourobject.
- Array.filter(function): returns filtered value from array based on
  truthy condition
- String.startsWith : return true or false if string passed starts with
  ('_')

Answer (score 1):

Try `.startsWith("_")` inside a filter.

```js
let myObj = {
  foo0: 'test',
  _foo1: 'test',
  _foo2: 'test',
  foo3: 'test',
};

function getSubscriptions(obj, cb) {
    // should return ["_foo1", "_foo2"]
    let ret = Object.keys(myObj).filter(v => v.startsWith("_"));

    return cb(ret);
}
getSubscriptions(myObj, (ret) => {
    if (match(ret, ["_foo1", "_foo2"]) ) { 
        $('.nope').hide();
        $('.works').show(); 
    }
   // $('.nope').show();  // you have misplaced these 2 lines
    //$('.works').hide();
});

function match(arr1, arr2) {
    if(arr1.length !== arr2.length) { return false; } 
    for(var i = arr1.length; i--;) { 
        if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) { return false;}  
    }
    return true; 
}
```

```css
body {
    background: #333;
    color: #4ac388;
    padding: 2em;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 19px;
}
.nope {
  color: #ce4242;
}
.container div{
  padding: 1em;
  border: 3px dotted;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="works">It Works!</div>
    <div class="nope">
    Doesn't Work...</div>
</div>
```